# iPhone Button Combo to View Owner Info?

Tags: iphone

Is there a button combo you can use on a locked iPhone to view it's owner info?

I once left my phone at airport security, and they called me on the PA system and showed me how they pressed a button combo to view the owner info.  I don't remember what the combo was.  I've found someone's phone now and would like to do the same to see if I can return it to them.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Are you referring to the [medical ID info](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207021)?  There's no button combo on an locked iPhone to view the owner info.

Comment: All the faffing [which the Emergency services *ought* to be trained in] to get to your emergency contacts… I still prefer this method -  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/298679/85275 - embed it in your lockscreen picture ;) No skill required, just lift the phone & there it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can tap on the Emergency button on the iPhone lock screen to access Medical ID. If a user has set Medical ID and has enabled it's display on the lock screen, the owner information can be obtained.

Here's how you can access it as well as set it up.

1. Suppose you found a random iPhone and attempt to unlock it. After failing to authenticate via Touch ID/Face ID, the iPhone would present you with the lock screen. It would look somewhat similar to this:

   [image]
2. Tap on Emergency and it would take you to the Emergency Call screen. If the owner has already setup Medical ID, it would be shown in the bottom left corner.

   [image]
3. You can tap on the Medical ID button to view the owner info. Important identifying information such as owner name, photo, height etc. along with Emergency contact numbers can be accessed if set.

   [image]
4. If you wish to set the Medical ID information for your own iPhone and want the same to be accessible via the lock screen, go to Settings app → Health → Medical ID and tap Edit to provide your information. Once done, enable Show When Locked under Emergency Access.

   [image]

Comment: You don't want us to know your weight :-)

Comment: @fsb Oh I don't want you to be envied by my fitness (weight + height). No kidding. :D.